# C# 4.0 Optional Parameters question

Tags: c#-4.0

I have an implementation like that:

```
 public interface IGenericRepository
 {
    //...
    void Update<T>(T entity, string keyPropertyName = "Id") where T : class;
    void Delete<T>(T entity, string keyPropertyName = "Id") where T : class;
    //...
}

public abstract class GenericRepositoryBase : IGenericRepository
{
    //...
    void Update<T>(T entity, string keyPropertyName = "Id") where T : class;
    void Delete<T>(T entity, string keyPropertyName = "Id") where T : class;
    //..
}

public class GenericRepository : GenericRepositoryBase
{
    //..
    public override void Update<T>(T entity, string keyPropertyName = "Id")
    {
       //..
    }

    public override void Delete<T>(T entity, string keyPropertyName = "Id")
    {
        //..
    }
    //..
}
```

Each time i am specifying(hard coding) keyPropertyName = "Id" it is looking not good.

May be some one has an idea how i may declare value `const string defaultKeyPropertyName = "Id"` just in one place and then everywhere just use like that.

```
//...
void Update<T>(T entity, string keyPropertyName = defaultKeyPropertyName) where T : class;
void Delete<T>(T entity, string keyPropertyName = defaultKeyPropertyName) where T : class;
//..
```

or it can be done somehow else?

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `const` if you want, and make a class that holds it. C# has no concept of a global variable, so this is as close as it will get:

```
public static class Defaults
{
    public const string KeyName = "Id";        
}

public abstract class GenericRepositoryBase
{
    //...
    protected abstract void Update<T>(T entity, string keyPropertyName = Defaults.KeyName) where T : class;
    protected abstract void Delete<T>(T entity, string keyPropertyName = Defaults.KeyName) where T : class;
    //..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK optional parameter values must be constants, so you cannot declare them anywhere.

Comment: The first half of your statement is correct but constants can be declared (almost) anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do not define a default value for `keyPropertyName` in the interface, but in the abstract class, then you could introduce the constant in the abstract class.

Comment: I did try that, but in such case Optional Parameter string keyPropertyName beaming not optional, but i wan to keep this optional thing too.